# How to define reusable classes with dynamic types inside?

Tags: java, generics, objectmapper

I have a class `SuccessResponse` that contains another custom class `SuccessCustomerResponseBody`, both of these classes are a POJO model for some XML structure.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")
public class SuccessResponse {

    private SuccessCustomerResponseBody ok;

    public SuccessCustomerResponseBody getOk() {
        return ok;
    }

    public void setOk(SuccessCustomerResponseBody ok) {
        this.ok = ok;
    }
}
```

and `SuccessCustomerResponseBody`

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SuccessCustomerResponseBody  {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "customers")
    private List<Customer> customers;
    private String requestId;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "customer")
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }
}
```

This model is used to fetch data from a database, and return as an XML response in service controller `GetCustomer`. It looks okay except when it's required to add another controller to return for example customer packages. So, the easiest way, to create two more classes like `SuccessPackageResponse` and `SuccessPackageResponseBody`, rename `SuccessResponse` to `SuccessCustomerResponse` and that's it. Well done

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")
public class SuccessPackageResponse {
    private SuccessPackageResponseBody ok;

    public SuccessPackageResponseBody getOk() {
        return ok;
    }

    public void setOk(SuccessPackageResponseBody ok) {
        this.ok = ok;
    }
}
```

`SuccessPackageResponseBody`

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SuccessPackageResponseBody {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "packages")
    private List<Package> packages;
    private String requestId;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "package")
    public List<Package> getPackages() {
        return packages;
    }
}
```

The main problem is that this approach produces a lot of code. So, I tried to re-use `SuccessResponse` by implementing this class as generic one.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")
public class SuccessResponse<T> {
    private T ok;

    public T getOk() {
        return ok;
    }

    public void setOk(T ok) {
        this.ok = ok;
    }
}
```

Looks better, right? We can use it like:

```
SuccessResponse<SuccessCustomerResponseBody> successCustomerResponse = objectMapper.convertValue(node.getMap().get("response"), SuccessResponse.class);
```

I thought that this is my solution, but I found that `ObjectMapper` configs are not applied in such approach and I don't understand why.

```
objectMapper.configOverride(String.class).setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));
```

To finalise, I have two questions:

1. Any idea how to re-use `SuccessResponse` in case when custom type (`SuccessCustomerResponseBody`) can be dynamically changed.
2. Why `ObjectMapper` config isn't applied in solution with generic?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the reason of losing `ObjectMapper` config is related to Java Type Erasure, because element type information is not available to Jackson in runtime.

So, to fix it I decided to use `TypeReference` to set correct type.

```
objectMapper.convertValue(node.getMap().get("response"), new TypeReference<MyCustomType>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found another way to resolve my issue with Generic Data type. JavaType is quite useful for my case. Please, see the code below

```
        JavaType customerResponseDataType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(SuccessResponse.class, SuccessCustomerResponseBody.class);
    SuccessResponse<SuccessCustomerResponseBody> successCustomerResponse = objectMapper.convertValue(node.getMap().get("response"), customerResponseDataType)
```

where `SuccessResponse.class`is generic with input type `SuccessCustomerResponseBody.class`